# how to convert a String value to arrayType in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column like below in a `pyspark dataframe`, the type is String:

[image]

Now I want to convert them to `ArrayType[Long]` , how can I do that?

Comment: which version of `spark` and `python` are you using ? b'coz  py3 has no long type.

Comment: you can write a simple udf to convert the existing data to array(long).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual data. It hurts users of screen readers and search engines. You should [edit] your post to include the text as text instead.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon OK，got it

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse as string and use split function to create an array

```
df.withColumn('cat_list',split(regexp_replace(col('cat_list'), '\[|\]',''),',').cast('array<float>').cast('array<long>'))
```